# Calculation within a pipe between different rows of a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble with a column of different numbers. I wish to calculate for every one of them how many others before them are within a certain range.

For example, let's say that range is 200 ; in the tibble below the result for the 5th number would be 2, that is the cardinality of the list {816, 705} whose numbers are above 872-1-200 = 671 but below 872.

[image]

I have thought of something along the lines of :

- for every theRow of the tibble, do calculate the vector `theTibble$number_list between(X,Y)` ;
- summing the boolean returned vector.

I have been told that using loops is less efficient.
Is there a clean way to do this within a pipe without using loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the way you asked for it, but you can use a bit of linear algebra. Should be more efficient and more simple than a loop.

```
number_list <- c(248,650,705,816,872,991,1156,1157,1180,1277)

m <- matrix(number_list, nrow = length(number_list), ncol = length(number_list))
d <- (t(m) - number_list)

cutoff <- 200

# I used setNames to name the result, but you do not need to
# We count inclusive of 0 in case of ties
setNames(colSums(d >= 0 & d < cutoff) - 1, number_list)
```

Which gives you the following named vector.

```r
 248  650  705  816  872  991 1156 1157 1180 1277 
   0    0    1    2    2    2    1    2    3    3
```

---

Here is another way that is pipe-able using `rollapply()`.

```r
library(zoo)

cutoff <- 200

df %>% 
  mutate(count = rollapply(number_list,
                           width = seq_along(number_list),
                           function(x) sum((tail(x, 1) - head(x, -1)) <= cutoff),
                           align = "right"))
```

Which gives you another column.

```r
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   number_list count
         <int> <int>
 1         248     0
 2         650     0
 3         705     1
 4         816     2
 5         872     2
 6         991     2
 7        1156     1
 8        1157     2
 9        1180     3
10        1277     3
```